# Cross-Validation Using Test Set

Tags: machine-learning

From what I have seen, cross-validation (CV) is largely done as part of training, not as part of testing the model? Some views here in this forum say you don't even need a test dataset. But if you're doing CV, can CV be done on a test set (after model building)?

Comment: I am not sure that fits the usual meaning of the words: *cross*-validation involves splitting the (training) data into $k$ folds and training a potential model $k$ times across the data minus each fold to see how it performs on that fold (then aggregating the $k$ results) so as to choose a model and tune its hyperparameters.  This split into folds does not make so much sense with the held-out test data.

Answer (score 0):

The test set should always be left untouched in order to be sure that you are predicting the Generalization Error because you want to predict how will your model perform under unseen data. On the other hand, CV is meant to be done on the training set in order to tune hyper-parameters in a correct way.

Comment: I am trying to collect multiple observations to run statistical tests on comparing model performance (against other types of models). So, I was thinking CV would help me do that once I have the final model. That's why I was associating CV with the test set.

Comment: What you are looking for is called nested cross validation, which works for comparing different models. However, this method still does not use the test set.

Comment: Can that be used to select across different types of models, e.g., logistic regression, random forest? I've seen CV referenced in terms of selecting across multiple versions of the same model but not across model types as much.

Comment: Yes. Take a look at this blog: https://ploomber.io/blog/nested-cv/